# Альтернатива long int в C

Tags: java, c++, c, типы-данных

Какой тип в Java соответствует типу `long int` в C?

Comment: Совершенно невероятно, но long.

Sorry, наврал. int. Джавовский long соответствует сишному long long int.

Comment: @alexlz, а на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995389/type-compatibility-in-languages пользователь Ahram сказал, что long.

Comment: У меня процессор 32-битный. Сишный long -- 4 байта.

Answer (score 5):

Зависит от платформы С. Если мы говорим об обычной a la Windows платформе, то сишный `long int` будет грубо соответствовать Java `int`, если о C на какой-то 64-х разрядной *nix платформе, то сишный `long int` будет похож/равен Java `long`

Где-то я встречал реализацию сишного int равного байту, так что допускаю, что есть в природе long int равный 2 байтам.

P.S. Есть еще ведь `signed/unsigned long int`, притом в Java нет `unsigned`

Comment: Лучшему-другу-всех-Айболитов: в java нет unsigned.

Comment: Бармалей, согласно стандарту С90 int имеет длину минимум 16 бит, а long - 32 бита. Однобайтовые инты были очень давно.

Comment: @alexlz был выпимши - дрогнула рука, конечно в Java все типа `signed` :)

Comment: @mikillskegg осталось только понять много ли портировщиков C знают про этот стандарт C90 особенно если портировали в 80-х годах

Comment: Если портировщик не знает этот стандарт, то.. ему надо его подучить.

Comment: @Barmaley и @mikillskegg занялись археологическими изысканиями?

Порты, разработчики которых не знают c90, можно найти только глубоко в архивах

Answer (score 3):

Как уже указал Бармалей, в Си стандартные типы не имеют строгого размера. Однако, можно использовать типы с фиксированной длиной - int32_t, int64_t из хедера stdint.h. Джавовскому long примерно соответствует int64_t.

Comment: @mikillskegg, тогда если я на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990929/parameter-passing-in-native-a-method захочу сделать public native long Traverser(String path) (у меня Nexenta 64 bit), то тогда реализация метода будет такой

    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_ParallelIndexation_Traverser(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring path)
    {
        long int result;
        const jbyte* path2 = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, nullptr);
        if (path2 == nullptr)
        return;
        result=Traverser(path2);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, path2);
        return result;
    }

Comment: А почему примерно?

Comment: @mikilskegg,  я не могу поменять сигнатуру long int 
Traverser(const char * sTraversingRoot) на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990929/parameter-passing-in-native-a-method, так как это повлечет другие изменения и эта функция не моя.

Comment: Тогда используйте везде long и не ошибетесь

Comment: @mikillskegg , вы сказали везде, поэтому я хочу уточнить: в long int Traverser(const char * sTraversingRoot) тип возвращамого значения нельзя изменить, поэтому там надо использовать long int, а в Java коде - long и jlong.